# keycloak custom spi docker not found

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-spi

I am trying to add a custom spi for keycloak. I would like to use docker to proceed. Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.8.4-openjdk-17 AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app/

RUN mvn clean package

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.7

COPY --from=build app/target/keycloak-spi-kafka.jar /opt/keycloak/providers

RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start-dev"]
```

Doing that, I am able to find my .jar file, however, when I launch my docker image, I am not able to find my custom spi. I think it should be accessible there:

[image]

but that is not the case...

I followed the official documentation [here](https://www.keycloak.org/server/containers) and to construct the eventListener, I followed [this](https://github.com/akoserwal/keycloak-integrations/tree/master/keycloak-spi-kafka) github repo.

If any of you have advice, that would be highly appreciate.

PS: when I run kc.sh show-config I can see that:

[image]

which seems to mean that my custom spi is added

PPS: Here is the link to my github repo, if it may help to have the code:

https://github.com/unik6065/keycloak-custom-spi

Comment: This is quiet hard to diagnose without the code. However, the github repository is 4 years old and rely on Kecyloak 11 when you are deploying on v23, did you at least upgrade the dependencies ?

Comment: Yes I’ve updated all the dependencies. Like I said: the .jar file is compiled and I am able to find it when I check using the kc.sh show config. For the code itself, I did not change anything except that I am not sending event to Kafka, I only kept the System.out.println.